# How to add double quotes to every value in env file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have an .env file and need to copy to an .env.sh file.
The command exports to .env.sh file:

```
scriptPath=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
printenv | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/export \1/g' > ${scriptPath}/.env.sh
```

my .env file:

```
DB_MYSQL_TYPE=mysql
DB_MYSQL_CONNECTOR=pymysql
DB_MYSQL_USER=tuandc
DB_MYSQL_PASS=mypass
DB_MYSQL_HOST=mysql.host
DB_MYSQL_PORT=3306
DB_MYSQL_DBNAME=vietnam
```

i 've exported it to .env.sh:

```
export DB_MYSQL_TYPE=mysql
export DB_MYSQL_CONNECTOR=pymysql
export DB_MYSQL_USER=tuandc
export DB_MYSQL_PASS=mypass~.(?Tweg
export DB_MYSQL_HOST=mysql.host
export DB_MYSQL_PORT=3306
export DB_MYSQL_DBNAME=vietnam
```

but i want to have double quotes to escape some special characters in DB_MYSQL_PASS:

```
printenv | sed -e 's/=\(.*\)/="\1/g' -e 's/$/"/g' >> ${scriptPath}/.env.sh
```

```
DB_MYSQL_TYPE="mysql"
DB_MYSQL_CONNECTOR="pymysql"
DB_MYSQL_USER="tuandc"
DB_MYSQL_PASS="mypass~.(?Tweg"
DB_MYSQL_HOST="mysql.host"
DB_MYSQL_PORT="3306"
DB_MYSQL_DBNAME="vietnam"
```

but i want to combine 2 regex above to make .env.sh file complete like this:

```
export DB_MYSQL_TYPE="mysql"
export DB_MYSQL_CONNECTOR="pymysql"
export DB_MYSQL_USER="tuandc"
export DB_MYSQL_PASS="mypass~.(?Tweg"
export DB_MYSQL_HOST="mysql.host"
export DB_MYSQL_PORT="3306"
export DB_MYSQL_DBNAME="vietnam"
```

Comment: Inside double quotes, `$`, backslash, backtick (and obviously `"`) are still a problem (and potentially characters whose encoding contains the encoding of those which in practice happens for backslash and backtick in some locales).  Single quotes are a much better choice, though you'd still need to handle `'` specially. See also [Escape a variable for use as content of another script](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/600214)

Comment: I wonder if something based on the shell's `declare -x -p` would be more robust than trying to wrangle the output of `printenv`?

Comment: @steeldriver: that actually seems like the best solution.

Comment: @steeldriver I don't think declare is present in POSIX but it would work well for bash

Comment: @SeetheMoar yes I suggested that based on the `bash` tag

Comment: It ‘ ‘goes without saying’ ’ that values with newline(s) will break pretty much anything you try to do in the realm of post-processing.  I guess the lesson here is that `printenv`, like ``ls``, is (arguably) a useful tool for producing output for display to users, but not for providing input to programs.  There; I said it.    :-)    ⁠        I see now that Stéphane Chazelas said this in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/697106/80216#697191) (although not in [his comment](/questions/697106/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-every-value-in-env-file#comment1317097_697106)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ declare -px
```

`declare` is a Bash builtin command that seems appropriate. This command escapes special characters for the shell in existing variable assignments.

Comment: To add to @gilaro 's answer, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73336215/1466168) of me with different flavours by shell. I never understood why printenv did not have an option to quote values.

Answer (score 1):

Easily done with `sed`, the Stream EDitor:

```
sed -i.bak -e `s/=/="/;s/$/"/` .env.sh
```

This does:

- `-i.bak` - edit in place, original file left as `.env.sh.bak`.
- `s/=/="/` - replace "`=`" with "`="`".
- `;` - command separator
- `s/$/"/` - match the end-of-line and add a quote.

Read `man sed`

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a single phase. With the original file (`.env`):

```
printenv | sed 's/\(^[^=]*\)=\(.*\)/export \1="\2"/' > "$scriptPath/.env.sh"
```

Comment: This is what the question asks for, but it would be a better answer if it disclosed that it probably isn’t what the OP really needs.

Answer (score 1):

The standard command to output all the environment variables mapped to shell variables as shell code that can be interpreted to set the same environment variables is `export -p`. `export` will take care of quoting the value as appropriate.

In the case `bash`'s `export` though, you need the `posix` option to be enabled (like when it's invoked as `sh`) for that output to be in `sh`-compatible syntax.

```
(set -o posix; export -p)
```

Though note that bash's `export` does use the `"..."` quotes for some values, which is not reliable when used with non ASCII text as the code may be interpreted differently when run in a different locale.

Also note that if a shell variable has been exported and not given any value, it will give: `export variable`.

Doing:

```
sh -c 'export -p'
```

Would address the latter, and potentially also the former if your `sh` is not `bash` and uses [the safer single quotes to quote the values](/a/600214).

If you consider that arbitrary environment variable values *and names* can contain newline characters (or single quotes or double quotes or non-text for that matters), it should become evident that the output of `printenv` cannot be post-processed reliably with line-based text utilities.

For example, with `printenv` here called with one (weirdly named) environment variable:

```
$ env -i $'$(reboot)\n=\n"$(reboot)"=\n$(reboot)' printenv
$(reboot)
=
"$(reboot)"=
$(reboot)
```

With the GNU implementations of `printenv` and `awk`, you could however do something reliable if limiting for instance to environment variables that are mappable to shell variables and whose name starts with `DB_MYSQL_`:

```
printenv -0 | LC_ALL=C gawk -v 'RS=\0' -v q="'" '
  function shquote(s) {
    gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
    return q s q
  }
  match($0, /^(DB_MYSQL_[_[:alnum:]]*=)(.*)$/, capture) {
    print "export " capture[1] shquote(capture[2])
  }'
```

Where the `-0` aka `--null` option of `printenv` causes `printenv` to print the environment variables NUL-delimited (and NUL contrary to newline cannot occur in an environment  name nor value), and we use single quotes instead of double quotes (with `'` in values inserted as `\'` outside of quotes), amd `LC_ALL=C` for every byte value to be considered valid text and the `[:alnum:]` character class to be limited to a-zA-Z0-9.

With `zsh`, you can do:

```
vars=(${(Mk)parameters[(R)scalar-export]:#DB_MYSQL_*})
(($#vars)) && export -p $vars
```

To print the definitions of scalar exported shell variables whose name starts with `DB_MYSQL_`. `zsh`'s `export` doesn't use `"..."` quoting but may use `$'...'` or leave some non-ASCII characters unquoted, which could also be a problem if the generate code is interpreted in a different locale from that where the code has been generated.

```
set -o extendedglob
for var (${(Mk)parameters[(R)scalar-export]:#DB_MYSQL_[a-zA-Z0-9_]#})
  print -r export $var=${(Pqq)var}
```

Where we always use single quotes and skip variable names with non-ASCII alnums would make it safer.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, guys,
I have found the solution
I concatenate 2 regexes,

```
printenv | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)$/export \1/g' -e 's/=\(.*\)/="\1/g' -e 's/$/"/g' >> ${scriptPath}/.env.sh
```